# file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Подскажите почему так

```
$options = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'timeout' => 6,
            'header'=>
                "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" .
                "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate\r\n" .
                "Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\r\n" .
                "Cache-Control:max-age=0\r\n" .
                "Connection:keep-alive\r\n" .
                "Host:www.satirikon.ru\r\n" .
                "If-Modified-Since:Wed, 31 Jan 2018 13:31:07 GMT\r\n" .
                "If-None-Match:08f695151c9e13d8beb4c98c79cfb94d\r\n" .
                "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1\r\n" .
                "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/63.0.3239.132 Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36\r\n"
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $res = file_get_contents('http://www.satirikon.ru', false, $context);
```

Выполняю код, возникает ошибка

> Message: file_get_contents(http://www.satirikon.ru):
>
> **failed to open stream**: HTTP request failed!

Заголовки поставил такие же, как у меня в браузере, когда открываю страницу. В чем может быть проблема?

Спасибо

Comment: Оберните в try/catch и проверьте в конфигурации флаг allow-url-fopen

Comment: спасибо! флаг в конфигурации on, такая проблема толкьо с одним сайтом

Comment: Данный код работает, проверил. Никаких ошибок не выдает. Но если у вас все на то пошло, используйте `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

Не так давно перестала работать гугл капча (Google Recaptcha v2) с вышеописанными симптомами. Поскольку URL запрашивался по HTTPS, а гугловский сертификат был относительно свежий и подписанный своим же корневым центром, подумал что может в репозиториях нет корневых сертификатов - установил их, но не помогло.

Проверил настройки PHP (модуль SSL установлен, file_get_contents = On).

Проблема оказалось банальней, хостер зачем-то подключил мне IPV6 и и запросы шли неизвестно куда, оставил только IPV4 и все заработало.

Comment: Ну чего сразу "зачем-то", за IPv6 будущее вообще-то

Comment: @andreymal но пока оно не наступило, имеем что имеем)